# Unwanted characters in SharePoint people picker.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am using a people picker control to get all SP users.When i click save button i am adding the users to a group and displaying users in a drop down list.But the users look like i:0#.f|m1010|arun8. I want this in eg: PCname\arun8.I am using a calendar list(event type).

```
      foreach (string UserSeperated in UsersSeperated)
               {
                         mySite.EnsureUser(UserSeperated);
                         SPUser User = mySite.SiteUsers[UserSeperated];                                            
                         oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                         oWeb.Groups["Presenters"].AddUser(User);
                         oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                         presenter = User.LoginName;  
                         presenterName = Environment.MachineName + "\\" + presenter ;
                         DDPresenter.Items.Insert(0, presenterName);                                                       
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Forms Bases Authentication, and that would explain why usernames contains `i:0#.f|m1010|`.

Try splitting the `User.LoginName`.

```
mySite.EnsureUser(UserSeperated);
SPUser User = mySite.SiteUsers[UserSeperated];                                            
oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
oWeb.Groups["Presenters"].AddUser(User);
oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
presenter = User.LoginName.Split('|')[2];  
presenterName = Environment.MachineName + "\\" + presenter ;
DDPresenter.Items.Insert(0, presenterName);
```

Comment: Split('i:0#.f|m1010|') is showing too many characters in character literal

Comment: presenter = User.LoginName.Split('|')[2];

Comment: @anish Ah, yes that's true. I updated it in my post.